# Easiest way to convert a line by line CSV into a comma CSV

Tags: linux, csv

I have a CSV file with several hundred thousand lines, single column, no spaces, no quotes, no commas.

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

and I need it to split into still 1 column, but a max of 50 of those lines into each line, separated by commas.

So:

```
line1,line2,line3,line4 all the way to line50
line51,line52,line53, all the way to line100
line101,line102,line103 all the way to line150
```

Until it's finished with the CSV.

I have FFE, CSVTOOLS, I'm running linux so really prefer a linux method.
It's definitely over my head, so please help, thanks.

Comment: Is python a viable option?

Comment: I'm can run py scripts, but I'm not familiar with python at all to make one myself.

Comment: "I have a CSV file with [...] no commas" - You know CSV stands for **comma** separated values?

Comment: I do know that, the file ends in .CSV but you're right, it might as well just be a plain text since that's what it is. I almost included that but didn't want to overexplain the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you can run `Perl` scripts.  I can't guarantee speed, but it will get the job done, given the details you have provided.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0];

open( my $fh, "<", $file ) or die $!;

my $cnt = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    ++$cnt;
    if ( $cnt < 50 ) {
        $_ =~ tr/\n/,/;
        print $_;
    }
    else {
        print "$_";
        $cnt = 0;
    }
}

close($fh);
```

You can run it as `perl convert.pl file` if you want it printed to standard output or just redirect it in the shell to a file too.

Comment: Wow thank you. Okay so save this as convert.pl and run it as perl convert.pl file.csv and it will save as the same file?

Comment: No, it will print to the terminal, just redirect it to another file to save the old file.  I suggest running `perl convert.pl file.csv > output.csv`

Comment: Okay your script looks spot on. Thank you SO much. It's echoing in the terminal though, what's the simplest way to get it to save it to another .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to read 50 lines from a file, then concatenate those using commas, right? Here's what I've come up with (using Python):

```
import sys;

fd = open("foo.txt");
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(50):
        line = fd.readline().rstrip()
        if (j != 0):
            sys.stdout.write(",")
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
fd.close()
```

Change `3` to the number of 50-line blocks and `"foo.txt"` to the actual filename. This writes to stdout; you can open another file for writing if that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

out_file=output.csv
line_width=50

count=0

while read line
do
  echo -n $line >> $out_file
  count=$(($count+1))

  if [ $count -lt $line_width ]
  then
    echo -n "," >> $out_file
  else
    echo "" >> $out_file
    count=0
  fi
done

# strip trailing commas
sed 's/,$//g' < $out_file > "$out_file.tmp" && mv "$out_file.tmp" $out_file
```

Say you have this script in `wrap.sh`, execute via command line:

```
$ ./wrap.sh < file.txt
```

The output will be in `output.csv`.